# Can every map from a summand be uniquely determined by the canonical projection

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $R$-modules, $C= A \oplus B$ and $f:M \longrightarrow A$ be an $R$-module homomorphism.
For every $R$-homomorphism $f$ and every module $A$ can we guarantee that there is a unique map $g:M \longrightarrow C$ such that $f=\pi_A \circ g$ , where $\pi_A:C \longrightarrow A$ is the canonical projection?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take $R=A=B=M=\mathbb{Z}$, $f=id$, and $g_1(x)=(x,0)$ the inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}$ into the first coordinate and $g_2(x)=(x,x)$ the diagonal inclusion. Then $\pi_1 g_i=f$ for both $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

Direct sums agree with direct product when there are only finitely many indices, and in this case, the product comes equipped with *two* projections. You need both of them to guarantee uniqueness.